# Magento 2 : All Completed Orders With Customer and Product Details

Tags: magento2, product, database, orders, sql

I'm planning to execute particular SQL query against magento database and use that result in data-analyzing-tool which requires uploading data to be in following format. [image: Data analyzing tool input data]

I need to know what are tables I should look into in order to create a SQL query to get above result. I'm using Magento Community Edition, version 2.1.6 which is latest version. Thank you!